# "\x01"[0] Why at the end of the string is present [0]

Tags: c++, arduino-ide, lcd

I have searched in many forums, but haven't found the answer to my question:

I'm trying to understand the software inside my 3D printer (Marlin firmware) and I found this c++ code:

```
#define LCD_STR_BEDTEMP     "\x00"
#define LCD_STR_DEGREE      "\x01"
#define LCD_STR_THERMOMETER "\x02"
#define LCD_STR_UPLEVEL     "\x03"
#define LCD_STR_REFRESH     "\x04"
#define LCD_STR_FOLDER      "\x05"
#define LCD_STR_FEEDRATE    "\x06"
#define LCD_STR_CLOCK       "\x07"
#define LCD_STR_ARROW_RIGHT "\x7E"  /* from the default character set */

lcd.createChar(LCD_STR_BEDTEMP[0], bedTemp);
lcd.createChar(LCD_STR_DEGREE[0], degree);
lcd.createChar(LCD_STR_THERMOMETER[0], thermometer);
lcd.createChar(LCD_STR_UPLEVEL[0], uplevel);
lcd.createChar(LCD_STR_REFRESH[0], refresh);
lcd.createChar(LCD_STR_FOLDER[0], folder);
lcd.createChar(LCD_STR_FEEDRATE[0], feedrate);
lcd.createChar(LCD_STR_CLOCK[0], clock);
```

`lcd.createChar` are Arduino commands which I have no problems with but the part I don't understand is why all of the `#define` strings finish with **[0]**?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `[0]` is an array indexing method, meaning take the first character.

Comment: Looks like roundabout way of using special characters. All of the strings contain 1 character. The `[0]` gets first character of that string. Why it was done in a way like it was - impossible to tell without more background.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand the last part.
this program is very complicated and many people coding different parts, so in all the program are present specification to avoid errors during **IDE** compilation
Anyway you answared to my question, thank you
P.S.
the programm needs of many unnecessary clarifications to be sure to have a correct compilation

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: Probably so that the normal strings can be used later in compiler concatenation, e.g. `"32 " LCD_STR_DEGREE`.

Answer (score 0):

All your macro produce string literals which are always \0 terminated. Please show the signature of `lcd.createChar` function. Perhaps it will be more clear what is the issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it just programs the chargen RAM for a HD44870U-compatible LCD controller. Since the chargen access is byte-oriented it makes sense to only use a `char`.

Comment: What do you mean by signature?

Comment: I mean what data types does the lcd.createChar take as parameters? I like to better understand your issue. So far my understanding is that you have inconvenience passing
`lcd.createChar(LCD_STR_BEDTEMP[0], bedTemp);`
instead of
`lcd.createChar(LCD_STR_BEDTEMP, bedTemp);`